# В чем ошибка, подскажите

Tags: ruby

```
    fieldOfLife = []

  for i in 0...100 do
   fieldOfLife[i] = rand (0..1)
  if (fieldOfLife[i] == 0)
     putc "0 "
   else 
     putc ". "
   end

   if (i % 10 == 0)
     puts ""
     end
i++
end
```

(repl):15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
  end
  ^~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i++` мне кажется здесь абсолютно лишним

Comment: Спасибо. Вчера без этого выдавало совершенно другую ошибку